# Como criar nova coluna com comparação entre colunas de tabelas diferentes em R?

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Pessoal estou com uma dificuldade no R e não sei como posso fazer isso. Eu tenho uma planilha excel e estou desenvolvendo um script em R, e estou preso em uma parte onde preciso fazer algo como um "PROCV", mas no R, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Objetivo: Tenho dois dataframes, um chamado "tb_consolidada" e "tbGEMOR", e ambos possuem uma coluna com este nome "R2500_PPNCOD", preciso que crie uma nova colunano df "tb_consolidada", e nessa nova coluna faça uma comparação entre as duas colunas, e o que achar de valores iguais ele retorna, senão retorna vazio.

Obstáculo: Como poderia ser feito, usar Lef_join seria o ideal? Na última etapa do código é onde tento fazer essa comparação. Porém não deu certo.

Dataframes utilizados no código: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1brWZ0h4uQSthZet5_b0KyDPTxwyExKwV

```html
#Importando dataframes que serão utilizados

metas1 <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/AlaxAtaide/Desktop/Metas/Metas 2022.xlsx", sheet = 1)
metas2 <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/AlaxAtaide/Desktop/Metas/Metas 2022.xlsx", sheet = 2)
metas3 <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/AlaxAtaide/Desktop/Metas/Metas 2022.xlsx", sheet = 3)

# Renomeando os cabeçalhos para ficar igual 
metas2 <- rename(metas2, R1900_CCSDATLIQ = R0900_CCSDATLIQ)
metas2 <- rename(metas2, R1900_CCSPCTTAXA = R0900_CCSPCTTAXA)
metas2 <- rename(metas2, R1900_CTCCHVCONTA = R0900_CTCCHVCONTA)
metas2 <- rename(metas2, R1900_CCSTIPLIQ = R0900_CCSTIPLIQ)

# Agrupando tbs 
tb_consolidada <- bind_rows(metas1, metas2)

# Remover coluna R1900_CTCCHVCONTA
tb_consolidada$R1900_CTCCHVCONTA <- NULL

#Remove linhas duplicadas da coluna PPNCOD 
tb_consolidada <- tb_consolidada[!duplicated(tb_consolidada$R2500_PPNCOD), ]

#Classifica coluna do maior para o menor (ordem decrescente)
tb_consolidada <- tb_consolidada[order(tb_consolidada$R1900_CCSDATLIQ, decreasing = TRUE), ]


#Cria tbGEMOR (Última tb Consolidada contendo todos os dados)
tbGEMOR<- read.xlsx("C:/Users/AlaxAtaide/Desktop/Metas/Redirecionamento_05122022_26122022v3_enviar.xlsx", sheet = 1)

#Criando nova coluna (existe?) para apresentar os dados retornados 
tb_consolidada$existentes <- rownames(tb_consolidada)
rownames(tb_consolidada) <- NULL

novo_df <- merge(tb_consolidada, tbGEMOR, by="R2500_PPNCOD")
```

Comment: Boas-vindas. Alex, É importante **[edit], remover o código complexo e no lugar adicionar um [mcve] (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)**, com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários)... Paulo e Alex evitem longas conversas em comentários, para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). *Agradecemos a compressão*.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141649/discussion-on-question-by-alex-santoro-como-criar-nova-coluna-com-comparacao-ent)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento realmente não entendo porque foi fechada, afinal é uma plataforma onde deveria ser para tirar dúvidas ou resolver problemas sobre determinada dificuldade. E não está me ajudando em nada para cada pergunta que eu abro é fechada por algum motivo sem contexto.

Comment: Triste, se nem mesmo em um fórum temos a liberdade para tirar dúvidas então não há sentido em existir esse fórum

Comment: Marcus e Alex, as regras são para todos. Foi solicitado que continuassem no chat e não aqui. Somos um site para a comunidade e não para indivíduos, as regras se aplicam a todos, você tem sim liberdade, basta [edit] a pergunta para que se adeque as regras que já lhes informei no primeiro comentário e assim que ajustar os problemas 5 usuários participantes do site irão reavaliar a pergunta e se ela estiver dentro das normas será reaberta. Liberdade não é o mesmo que sem regras.